# Difference in Resetting Form with Javascript getElementById Versus Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

When resetting my form, this works: `document.getElementById("flagform").reset();`

But this does not: `$("#flagform").reset();`

Trying to understand the difference.  The latter has no object reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Javascript example `reset` is being run against a DOM element while in the jQuery example it's running against a jQuery Object.  Use the `[0]` accessor to get the selected DOM element out of the jQuery object.

```
$('#flagform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: You can also use `$('#flagform').get(0).reset();`.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize that Jquery worked that way. Thanks!